# Why we use "var" instead of String or Number or Boolean (primitives) in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Why we use "var" when we have String , Number and Boolean primitives in javascript.

```
var str = 'Sample String';

String str = 'Sample String';
```

What is the best practice and why ?

Comment: Because that's how the language is defined.

Answer (score 4):

> Why we use `var` instead of `String`?

Because JavaScript is a [dynamically typed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language#Static_versus_dynamic_typing) language by design. A variable named `str` might store a String when initialized, but a Number (or value of any other type) later: types won't be checked at any point. When the language was created, it was considered an advantage.

In fact, we only use `var` to make a specific name local to a specific scope; it's highly recommended, but not even required (unless 'strict mode' is on). Using `String` (or any other type name - actually, the name of the corresponding constructor function) would cause a syntax error.

Answer (score 0):

**var** in javascript is used to declare a local variable

```
var myVariable = "";          // Local scope Variable

myVariable = "";              // Declare on Global scope window.myVariable (if not declared in the local scope)

String str = 'Sample String'; // Throw SyntaxError
```

So if you want to declare a variable you should use the var keyword,
else you could reach some mistake when you think you are using a local variable like this :

```
 for (i = 0, i < 10 ; i++){ // Global variable i === window.i
```